# Execution order with multiple commands

Tags: shell, cron

I'm relatively new to Linux and I'm working on a CronTab for scheduled backups.
I figured out how to do multiple sequential jobs with `;` and `&&`, but I'm unsure how the dependency affects the sequence.

My cron job looks like this:

```
# Every day at 0:00 (reboot server and do the hourly backup procedure).
0 0 * * * sh shutdown.sh && sh backup.sh ; sh nas.sh ; sh ftp.sh ; sh startup.sh
```

What I want to happen is to run shutdown.sh and continue the sequence if it's successful, but cancel it if it fails. My fear is it will only skip `sh backup.sh` but then continue the sequence.

Will it work as intended? If not, would something like `shutdown && (backup ; nas ; ftp ; startup)` be possible?

Comment: It will work as written so long as you `exit 1` *(or anything other than `0`)* from `shutdown.sh` in the event of a failure.

Comment: The whole thing should be a script, so that it's easy to debug and test. Your cron then just call that 1 script (which can then contain "if" statements, etc)

Comment: That is a good idea, I will do that. This was mostly a working document to visualize my intentions easier.

Comment: Maybe just write a script that executes all the commands, and schedule that script instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why don't you test it with some dummy commands that you know will work or fail?

```
$ ls foo && echo ok1 ; echo ok2
ls: cannot access foo: No such file or directory
ok2

$ ls foo && (echo ok1 ; echo ok2)
ls: cannot access foo: No such file or directory
```

So it seems like your intuition was correct, and you need the second structure.

---

As [suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137162/execution-order-with-multiple-commands/137170?noredirect=1#comment219227_137170) by [mikeserv](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/52934/mikeserv), for testing in general, you can use `true` (or `:`) and `false`, instead of `ls` of a non-existent file. Hence,

```
$ false && echo ok1 ; echo ok2
ok2

$ false && (echo ok1 ; echo ok2)
```

Comment: Of course, I should have done that. The reason I asked is that I'm not familiar with command formatting. But thank you!

Comment: No worries. It's still a good question (+1). I tend not to trust any answers immediately anyway, and prefer ones that I can test myself.

Comment: @Sparhawk - I like that philosophy - it's one I subscribe to as well. You might find it a little easier to do in future with `:` and `false` though.

Comment: @mikeserv Paranoia is good. :) I did think about using `true` and `false`, and almost edited it in, but I thought `ls` of an non-existent file was clearer, since you could see an error message, and it was more "real world". It's still good advice though, so I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @Sparhawk - the output was a good point. Its no better really, but maybe handy when you want to fail and `echo ... >&2` in the same call: `(${unset?...}) || executed`

Answer (score 0):

if shutdown.sh really reboots your server, i don't think the other commands will get executed??
answer might be deleted, but you can read it, so here are just some hints:
place the scripts in an own folder and call them with full path, cron might run in a different folder.
making them executable and calling them directly without sh is nice too.
putting the whole logic in an extra script with an if-else is good coding too.
if you worry about sh being used as shell, use a shebang.

Comment: This is for a server instance running on a Debian box.

Comment: as long as you know what you do it's fine then :)